# track mouse position for making a hole in a canvas HTML5

Tags: html, video, canvas, position, mouse

I'm trying to make something a little bit to complicated for my skills, maybe.
What i want to do is:

- play a video on canvas 0 (z-index:1)
- play a video on canvas 1 (z-index:2)
- make a circle hole in canvas 2
- make the hole follow the mouse position (while on the canvas);

I've written this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>


<style>
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#myCanvas {
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
    height:400px;
    width:700px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
#myCanvas1 {
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
    height:400px;
    width:700px;
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:0px;
}
#BIG{
    height:800px;
    width:800px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;       

}
#v{
    position:absolute;
    top:600px;
    height:40px;
    width:100px;
}
#v1{
    position:absolute;
    top:500px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
}
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>

    var centerX= 200;
    var centerY= 200;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){


    },false);

        function draw(v,c,w,h,v1,c1, radius, centerX, centerY) {



            if(v.paused || v.ended){
                v1.pause();
                return false;
            }


            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2* Math.PI, true);
            c.clip();






            c.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);

            c1.drawImage(v1,0,0,w,h);
            setTimeout(draw,20,v,c,w,h,v1,c1, radius, centerX, centerY);



        }

        function getMousePos(canvas, evt){
            // get canvas position
            var obj = canvas;
            var top = 0;
            var left = 0;
            while (obj && obj.tagName != 'BODY') {
                top += obj.offsetTop;
                left += obj.offsetLeft;
                obj = obj.offsetParent;
            }

            // return relative mouse position
            var mouseX = evt.clientX - left + window.pageXOffset;
            centerX=mouseX;
            var mouseY = evt.clientY - top + window.pageYOffset;
            centerY=mouseY;
            return {
                x: mouseX,
                y: mouseY
            };
        }

        function writeMessage(canvas, message ,x){
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            context.font = '18pt Calibri';
            context.fillStyle = 'black';


            context.fillText(x, 10, 25);
        }

        window.onload = function(){

                var v = document.getElementById('v');
                var v1=document.getElementById('v1');
                var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var canvas1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
                var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');

                var cw = Math.floor(canvas.clientWidth );
                var ch = Math.floor(canvas.clientHeight );

                canvas.width = cw;
                canvas.height = ch;
                canvas1.width = cw;
                canvas1.height = ch;

                var radius = 70;

                 canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt){
                         var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
                        var message = "Mouse position: " + mousePos.x + "," + mousePos.y;
                        writeMessage(canvas, message, mousePos.x);

                    }, false);

                v.addEventListener('play', function(){


                    draw(this,context,cw,ch, v1, context1, centerX, centerY, radius);

                    v1.play();

                    },false);


        };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="BIG">
            <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>


        </div>
        <video id="v1" >
            <source src=video.webm type=video/webm>
            </video>
            <video id="v" controls >
                <source src=video.mp4 type=video/mp4>
                </video>

                <span>

                </span>
            </body>
            </html>
```

But I'm doing something wrong because it makes the hole, but the hole doesn't follow the pointer. Any ideas? I'm ready to start again from scratch, but I need some help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution I've found:`

```
<style>
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background:#010101;
    color:#EEE;
    height:700px;
    text-align:center;
}
#title{
    position:relative;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #888;
}
#Regia{
    position:relative;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    top:425px;
}
#myCanvas {
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
    height:400px;
    width:700px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
#myCanvas1 {
    border: 1px solid #9C9898;
    height:400px;
    width:700px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 54px -10px #555; /* Saf3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
              box-shadow: 5px 5px 54px -10px #555; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, FF4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
}
#BIG{
    height: 500px;
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -350px;
}
#v{
    position:relative;
    top:425px;
    height:0px;
    width:700px;
}
#v1{
    position:absolute;
    top:500px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
}
</style>
<script>

    var centerX= 20;
    var centerY= 20;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){


    },false);

        function draw(v,c,w,h,v1,c1, radius) {



            if(v.paused || v.ended){
                v1.pause();

            }
            c.save();
            c.clearRect(0, 0, 700, 400);
            c.globalAlpha=1;                
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2* Math.PI, false);              
            c.clip();
            c.drawImage(v,0,0,w,h);         
            c.restore();                
            c1.drawImage(v1,0,0,w,h);
            setTimeout(draw,33,v,c,w,h,v1,c1, radius);
        }

        function getMousePos(canvas, evt){
            // get canvas position
            var obj = canvas;
            var top = 0;
            var left = 0;
            while (obj && obj.tagName != 'BODY') {
                top += obj.offsetTop;
                left += obj.offsetLeft;
                obj = obj.offsetParent;
            }

            // return relative mouse position
            centerX= evt.clientX - left + window.pageXOffset;
            centerY = evt.clientY - top + window.pageYOffset;


        }



        window.onload = function(){

                var v = document.getElementById('v');
                var v1=document.getElementById('v1');
                var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var canvas1 = document.getElementById('myCanvas1');
                var context1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');

                var cw = Math.floor(canvas.clientWidth );
                var ch = Math.floor(canvas.clientHeight );

                canvas.width = cw;
                canvas.height = ch;
                canvas1.width = cw;
                canvas1.height = ch;

                var radius = 80;

                 canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt){
                         getMousePos(canvas, evt);


                    }, false);

                v.addEventListener('play', function(){


                    draw(this,context,cw,ch, v1, context1, radius);

                    v1.play();

                    },false);


        };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="title"><H1>Test Lente HTML5 - Online</h1></div>

        <div id="BIG">
            <canvas id="myCanvas1" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
            <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
            <video id="v" controls="controls" >
                <source src=video0.mp4 type=video/mp4></source>
                    <source src=video0.ogg type=video/ogg></source>
                        <source src=video0.webm type=video/webm><p>Your browser can’t play HTML5 video.</p></source>
                </video>
                <div id="Regia">    <p>Streaming Test</p></div>

        </div>
        <video id="v1" muted="muted" >
            <source src=video1.webm type=video/webm></source>
                <source src=video1.mp4 type=video/mp4></source>
                    <source src=video1.ogg type=video/ogg></source>
            </video>


                <span>

                </span>
            </body>
            </html>
```

I've made some clear changes. 
Now steps are:

- Draw video0 on canvas0
- Draw a circle in canvas1
- Clip it and RESTORE
- THEN draw video 1 on canvas1

I know that maybe x and y mouse variables are not so polite being global... Any other good solution is appreciated!

`